# LEDs for high temperature applications

Tags: led, temperature

I need a LED in an application, where the temperature cycles from 0 - 125 degree C.
All I can find is LED´s that goes to 85 degree C, can that be true?

Comment: Colour? Power rating? Desired lifetime? Usage duration / duty cycle? Why 125C? More data gives better answers

Comment: The LED mentioned by Anindo GHosh looks possibly useful - [datasheet here](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/opto/led/chip_mono/psl0101.pdf) BUT note that 130 C is its maximum operating temperature and that it is derated at about 9 ma / degree C from 500 mA at 75C to 0 mA at 130C - or about 45 mA at 125 C. In practice you could PROBABLY run it slightly higher or hotter and accept a lower lifetime BUT you'd need to investigate further. Available at Digikey.

Comment: Highest I've found is 300 deg F look for work lights for high temp apps.MWL-14-extreme

Answer (score 7):

High temperature LEDs do exist in SMD form factors: Look for LEDs with full **ceramic substructure** and high temperature bonds (typically silver or silver-plated). These are designed to withstand temperatures up to and above 125 degrees Centigrade.

One such example is the ROHM [PSL01 LED](http://www.rohm.com/web/global/new-products?newproduct-title=high-heat-resistance-high-power-white-leds-psl01-series), that is rated for operation up to 130 degrees C.